# Spring MVC: setComplete() does not guarantee the session cleanup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I am solving quite tricky issue that *sometimes* user sees values from their previous session. I have the Spring MVC controller which handles AJAX requests from the user. I have the next 2 handler methods:

```
@PostMapping("/notifications")
void performLongRunningOperation() {
    // some operation which may take about 10 seconds
}

@PostMapping("/cancel")
void cancel(SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
}
```

The problem is that if `cancel()` finishes execution *before* `performLongRunningOperation()` finishes execution, then `setComplete()` has no effect. More precisely, `setComplete()` cleans the session up, but then the session gets restored to the state which was during execution of 
 the `performLongRunningOperation()` method.

The only solution I found is to not use `setComplete()` at all and instead manage the session state manually (i.e., keep an instance of some `SessionHolder` object in the session and set to null the fields of this object when the user requests the cancellation of the session). The solution fixed the initial issue, but now I need to care about proper synchronization for the `SessionHolder`.

The question is: how should the `setComplete()` method be used in a scenario when one do not know exactly the order in which the handler methods are going to finish execution (if it can be used at all)?

The working Spring Boot project which demonstrates the issue is [here](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/spring-session-sandbox/src/main/java/com/yaskovdev/sandbox/spring/session/NotificationController.java).

Comment: It turns out that it is a limitation of Spring. The ticket to get rid of this limitation is here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16306.